# Complex String to List in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I m converted Object of the List to string and saving in database.
I want is to while fetching back from database parse back to List of Object

```
[
  {
    "name": "Dart",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Flutter",
    "value": 1
  }
]
```

above is sample data I m fetching back from the database.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your data is in the [JSON](https://json.org) format. In that case, it is as easy as using [`jsonDecode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html) on your `String`:

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = jsonDecode(string);
```

Check out [this working demo](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/5d163a88142aea40ddb67cba56fe7f93).

Learn more about [JSON and serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json).

Comment: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 3) [{name:google,value:0}]

Comment: @aryansingh You need to have JSON data. The data you put in your comment is not formatted data. That will not work then. What API does not return JSON?

Comment: I used jsonEncode() while saving data in the database , now working